# C# - Зацикливание выполнения части кода

Tags: c#

Как зациклить выполнение данного кода C#?

Дабы оно постоянно проверяло, запущен ли процесс `steam` и включало\выключало процесс.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("steam");
    if (pname.Length == 0)
        Process.Start("csgo");
    else
    {
        foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo"))
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
while (true)
{
    // тут ваш код
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // пауза в одну секунду, мы ж не хотим перегревать процессор?
}
```

Comment: в такой случае если процесс steam не запущен,оно начинает запускать новый процесс csgo и так пока не сгорит проц)).Как сделать так ,что если процесс (csgo) уже все таки запущен ,оно не запускало его снова ?

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников: Это уже следующий вопрос :) Ну проверьте точно так же наличие csgo в памяти через `Process.GetProcessesByName(...).Length` перед запуском.

Comment: Огромное спасибо,все получилось :)

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников: Пожалуйста!